# Virtual Machine that sees third (data) partition

Tags: macos, boot-camp, vmware-fusion, parallels

I have a Mac with three partitions: MacOSX (HFS), Data (NTFS), Windows-Bootcamp (NTFS).

Is there ANY configuration that allows Windows see the "Data" partition when run as a virtual machine? (it sees it fine when booted to bootcamp natively)

VMWare Fusion, Parallels or anything? I desperately need that setup.

PS. Found this [guide](http://www.sakeoftruth.com/2010/02/parallels-third-partition/) for parallels, it's exactly what I need but it's for Parallels ver.**4** thats kinda old version, the XML file is now different... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say which version of OS X you are running. You may need to load up an NTFS driver to access the partition within MacOS which would then allow Fusion or Parallels to map to it as a remote (network) folder.

That's how I access the directories on my partitions that are not part of the VM files.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to mount the NTFS Volume "Data" with Dick utility, and then connect it to Parallels. You shouldn't need any third party applications to mount NTFS. Support for NTFS goes back to Mac OS X 10.5 So, Leopard, Snow Leopard, and Lion all support NTFS, unfortunately the Mac OS will only be able to read the volumes. If you need write, download NTFS-3g (no relationship to 3g wireless serv